# how to move the background running app to foreground by its package name

Tags: android

I am having question regarding launching and resuming the already running apps.I had gone through various methods to solve this problem but it always created new instance if the particular app is already running.I had tested some apps like `Omni swipe`,`EAS:Easy App Switcher`,etc; these type of apps can successfully resume the particular background running app.I have no idea how do they move the running app to foreground and resumes it perfectly.I think they use `queryIntentActivites()` but I don't know about it perfectly.Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably done with [`ActivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html), using methods like [`moveTaskToFront()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#moveTaskToFront(int,%20int)) in conjunction with the id of a [`RunningTaskInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html).

Comment: can you explain me with some code and details of it.It may be very helpful.

Comment: can you explain me with some code and details of it.It may be very helpful.